# how to use annyang in input text for special characters

Tags: javascript, annyang

I am using annyang for voice recognition. For all things it is working fine but in login page I want to insert username and password by annyang only. username and password contain special symbols so how can I used annyang for this.
like if useraname contain " _ " (underscore). if I used it in Annyang then it is inserting text "underscore" instead of symbol " _ ".

```
function initAnnyang(){

if (annyang) {
  var commands = {
        'redirect login page': function(){
            redirectLogin();
        },
        'focus username' : function(){
            $('#username').focus();
        },  
        'type username *username' : function(username){
            $('#username').val(username);
        },
        'focus password' : function(){
            $('#password').focus();
        },  
        'type password *password' : function(password){
            $('#password').val(password);
        },
        'click on login' : function(){
            $('#sumbit').click();
        },
        'show start menu' : function(){
            showStartMenu();
        },
        'open my computer' : function(){
            openMyComputer();
        }

    }
  };  
  annyang.addCommands(commands);
  annyang.debug();  
  annyang.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking i came to the  point that I can speak foe special symbols but while writing into the function I will convert special symbol text to special symbol. like if user will say write `"abc underscor d"` then it will replace the word `underscore` to special symbol `'_'` at run time.